# Can the clause "A doubles B" mean A is twice as many/much as B?

Tags: comparison

> *...Conversely, from 1995 to 2015, a net increase was seen in the figure for females, which jumped to approximately 3000 in 2010 before declining to 2000, **[being double/doubling]** that for males in the last year examined.*

I wonder if I should use **being double**  or **doubling** or neither of them in this sentence. I feel like **being double** is more correct, but I'm not so sure.
[image]

Comment: I know it's all fake, but I can't see any trend or pattern in those data.  They look exactly what random numbers look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb "double" means to duplicate or to change by a factor of two.  You can say "The number of cats is double the number of dogs", (with the adjective "double") but not "the number of cats doubles the number of dogs".

Your particular data are in a mess, with no discernable trend or pattern. That makes it exceptionally difficult to "tell the story", since there is no story to tell.  It's far harder to describe a random sequence of numbers than to describe numbers that follow a trend.

Comment: I know, right? This chart is absurd. Still, grammatically speaking, is "being double" the correct choice?

Comment: Yes,  but this is not the sort of question I'd like to get!

Comment: May I ask why? I mean this exam question is bad, but the piece of knowledge I asked you above might be useful for people in other situations.

Comment: Well it's like I said in the answer.  What IELTS want you to do is to "tell the story" of the data, using a variety of verb tenses and aspects.  But when the numbers are essentially a random series, there is no story to tell. So what is the poor test taker to do? If this was "real",  you would have had some hypotheses to test, eg "Gym membership has increased" or "More men use the gym".  You would then be able to answer in the form "These data support/don't support the hypothesis".

Comment: So the "real" answer is "There are no clear trends in these data.  Gym membership has fluctuated widely over the period.  There is insufficient evidence to support the hypothesis that more men or women use the gym."  But that's not what the person who set the test wants...  This is because **the people who create English tests for IELTS are mathematically illiterate and have no understanding of data!** They probably never took a maths class beyond age 16 and have about the same level of maths as an average 12 year-old.

Comment: Sadly, this is still a certificate required by so many universities and companies in the world. Millions of people take it every year. I'm getting bored of it, but that's what I have to do. It's not like we can argue with them about how to create a test, so when we encounter a bad one, the only thing we can do is to find a way to deal with it. I hope native speakers understand this and are still willing to help test takers.

Comment: I can't stress enough how grateful I am for discovering this forum. I've used other forums before, but none of them are nearly as helpful as this. I remember feeling amazed by the long answer that a user gave me when I first asked a question, and even now sometimes I still am. This mentality here is truly inspiring to me. Thank you so much!